# Test whether variable is defined, but not initialized

Tags: defvar

**Q**:  How can I test (programmatically) whether a variable has been defined, but not initialized?

```
(defvar foo)
```

**EXAMPLE**:

```
(if (my-test foo)
  (message "%s has been defined, but not initialized." foo)
  (message "%s has been defined AND initialized." foo))
```

Comment: The problem is that, at the lowest level of LISP, just mentioning a variable (technically an atom in LISP) makes it exist.  To ask the question of whether it exists, you have to mention it, so the answer is always Yes.  The `defvar` _does_ do a bit more that just make the variable exist, but I'm not sure any of that would be good enough.  If you don't care about that distinction, you could use `boundp` which just tests if there's a value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following works only with lexical binding, because with dynamic binding `(defvar foo)` has no real effect.  It checks whether let-binding the variable affects the dynamic value or not.  I used the term "declared" instead of "defined", because `(defvar foo)` doesn't quite feel like a full definition to me (e.g., it only applies to the file it's in) so it's more like C's "declare".

```el
;; -*- lexical-binding: t -*-

(defvar foo 2)
(defvar bar)

(defmacro check-var (var)
  `(message "%s %s"
            ',var
            (cond ((boundp ',var) "has been initialized")
                  ((let ((,var t)) (boundp ',var))
                   "has been declared, but not initialized")
                  (t "has NOT been declared nor initialized"))))

(check-var foo)
(check-var bar)
(check-var qux)
```